# Save Tkinter window of Labels to image file

Tags: python, tkinter

I am hoping to create a `Tkinter` `Frame` or `Canvas` that subsequently gets saved as a image file (something other than postscript). The `Frame` will be primarily `Labels`. Everything else I've found elsewhere on SO involves taking a screenshot (using `ImageGrab` or similar), but this method (see MRE below) isn't actually taking an image of the canvas. It is grabbing incomplete portions of the canvas and portions of other parts of the user's screen. Obviously that's some kind of problem with my coordinates, but ultimately, I'd like to just save the whole thing as a image without having to necessarily show it on screen at all. So if there's a way to avoid the screengrab entirely, that would be ideal.

My desired outcome is a .png (or gif or bmp) of the on-screen Tkinter canvas that pops up. Thanks!

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageGrab

class TestClass(Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        self.parent = parent
        Frame.__init__(self)
        self.main = self.master
        self.f = Frame(self.parent)
        self.f.pack()
        self.can=Canvas(self.f)
        self.can.pack(side='left', fill='both', expand=True)
        
        (Label(self.can, text='Hi there', width=15)
            .grid(column=0, row=0, padx=10, pady=10))
        (Label(self.can, text='Do not panic', width=15)
            .grid(column=0, row=2, padx=10, pady=10))
        (Label(self.can, text='Count the heads!', width=15)
            .grid(column=0, row=3, padx=10, pady=10))
        
        self.can.update()
        x=self.can.winfo_rootx()+self.can.winfo_x()
        y=self.can.winfo_rooty()+self.can.winfo_y()
        x1=x+self.can.winfo_width()
        y1=y+self.can.winfo_height()
        box=(x,y,x1,y1)
        
        print(box)
        grabcanvas = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=box)
        grabcanvas.show()
        grabcanvas.save('test.png')
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root=Tk()
    ui = TestClass(root)
    ui.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save a table of text as an image without displaying it, the move is to put it into a `matplotlib` `table` and then hide the plot ax. If I wanted to get fancier, I'd use some other `matplotlib` text functionality, but the example below serves the purpose.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

txt = ['Hi there', 'Do not panic', 'Count the heads!', 
        'Milliways', 'Mosty Harmless']

df_data = {'Text': txt,
            'Numbers':np.random.randint(1, 10, 5)}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=df_data)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

table = ax.table(cellText=df.values, 
                colLabels=df.columns, 
                loc='upper center')

ax.axis('off')
fig.savefig('test.png')
```